# Cannot plot dataframe as barh because TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have been all over this site and google trying to solve this problem.
It appears as though I'm missing a fundamental concept in making a plottable dataframe.
I've tried to ensure that I have a column of strings for the "Teams" and a column of ints for the "Points"
Still I get: TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

```
import csv
import pandas
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

set_of_teams = set()

def load_epl_games(file_name):
    with open(file_name, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        raw_data = {"HomeTeam": [], "AwayTeam": [], "FTHG": [], "FTAG": [], "FTR": []}
        for row in reader:
            set_of_teams.add(row["HomeTeam"])
            set_of_teams.add(row["AwayTeam"])
            raw_data["HomeTeam"].append(row["HomeTeam"])
            raw_data["AwayTeam"].append(row["AwayTeam"])
            raw_data["FTHG"].append(row["FTHG"])
            raw_data["FTAG"].append(row["FTAG"])
            raw_data["FTR"].append(row["FTR"])
        data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data=raw_data)
    return data_frame

def calc_points(team, table):
    points = 0
    for row_number in range(table["HomeTeam"].count()):
        home_team = table.loc[row_number, "HomeTeam"]
        away_team = table.loc[row_number, "AwayTeam"]
        if team in [home_team, away_team]:
            home_team_points = 0
            away_team_points = 0
            winner = table.loc[row_number, "FTR"]
            if winner == 'H':
                home_team_points = 3
            elif winner == 'A':
                away_team_points = 3
            else:
                home_team_points = 1
                away_team_points = 1
            if team == home_team:
                points += home_team_points
            else:
                points += away_team_points
    return points

def get_goals_scored_conceded(team, table):
    scored = 0
    conceded = 0
    for row_number in range(table["HomeTeam"].count()):
        home_team = table.loc[row_number, "HomeTeam"]
        away_team = table.loc[row_number, "AwayTeam"]
        if team in [home_team, away_team]:
            if team == home_team:
                scored += int(table.loc[row_number, "FTHG"])
                conceded += int(table.loc[row_number, "FTAG"])
            else:
                scored += int(table.loc[row_number, "FTAG"])
                conceded += int(table.loc[row_number, "FTHG"])
    return (scored, conceded)

def compute_table(df):
    raw_data = {"Team": [], "Points": [], "GoalDifference":[], "Goals": []}
    for team in set_of_teams:
        goal_data = get_goals_scored_conceded(team, df)
        raw_data["Team"].append(team)
        raw_data["Points"].append(calc_points(team, df))
        raw_data["GoalDifference"].append(goal_data[0] - goal_data[1])
        raw_data["Goals"].append(goal_data[0])
    data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data=raw_data)
    data_frame = data_frame.sort_values(["Points", "GoalDifference", "Goals"], ascending=[False, False, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
    data_frame.index = numpy.arange(1,len(data_frame)+1)
    data_frame.index.names = ["Finish"]
    return data_frame

def get_finish(team, table):
    return table[table.Team==team].index.item()

def get_points(team, table):
    return table[table.Team==team].Points.item()

def display_hbar(tables):
    raw_data = {"Team": [], "Points": []}
    for row_number in range(tables["Team"].count()):
        raw_data["Team"].append(tables.loc[row_number+1, "Team"])
        raw_data["Points"].append(int(tables.loc[row_number+1, "Points"]))
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=raw_data)
    #df = pandas.DataFrame(tables, columns=["Team", "Points"])
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
    df["Points"].apply(int)
    print(df.dtypes)
    df.plot(kind='barh',x='Points',y='Team')

games = load_epl_games('epl2016.csv')
final_table = compute_table(games)
#print(final_table)
#print(get_finish("Tottenham", final_table))
#print(get_points("West Ham", final_table))
display_hbar(final_table)
```

The output:

```
              Team  Points
0          Chelsea      93
1        Tottenham      86
2         Man City      78
3        Liverpool      76
4          Arsenal      75
5       Man United      69
6          Everton      61
7      Southampton      46
8      Bournemouth      46
9        West Brom      45
10        West Ham      45
11       Leicester      44
12           Stoke      44
13  Crystal Palace      41
14         Swansea      41
15         Burnley      40
16         Watford      40
17            Hull      34
18   Middlesbrough      28
19      Sunderland      24
Team      object
Points     int64
dtype: object
Team      object
Points     int64
dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/Programming/Python/Premier League.py", line 99, in <module>
    display_hbar(final_table)
  File "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/Programming/Python/Premier League.py", line 92, in display_hbar
    df.plot(kind='barh',x='Points',y='Team')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-    packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 2941, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
**kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1804, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 258, in generate
    self._compute_plot_data()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 373, in _compute_plot_data
'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

What am I doing wrong in my display_hbar function that is preventing me from plotting my data?

Here is the [csv file](http://www.filedropper.com/epl2016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should swap `x` and `y` in `df.plot(...)`. Because `y` must be numeric according to the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html).

Comment: I appreciate that, I knew it was something small +1 for explaining why instead of just providing the code correction and thanks for the documentation.
Now I just have to read more to figure out why the df is in the proper order but the bar graph is inverted.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.plot(x = "Team", y="Points", kind="barh");
```

[image]